# How to provide an XMLHttpRequest promise to a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, xmlhttprequest

Messing around with an autocomplete plugin available at https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-4-autocomplete, and the following works:

```
$('#id').autocomplete({
    source: {'test1':1, 'test2':2, 'test1':3}
});
```

Instead of local JSON, will need to make an XMLHttpRequest and was thinking something like the following, and while I don't get an error, I also don't get anything:

```
$('#id').autocomplete({
    source: function() {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                return JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            }
        };
        xhttp.open(method, url, true);
        xhttp.send();
    }
});
```

The plugin's author made the following [remark](https://github.com/Honatas/bootstrap-4-autocomplete/issues/2#issuecomment-532801557) a while back:

> I don't have plans to directly invoke any url inside the lib. What you
> can do is set autocomplete to your textfield after your ajax call
> returns, which you can do with jQuery, like this:
>
> $.ajax('myurl').then((data) => $('#myTextfield').autocomplete({
> source: data }));
>
> You don't have to worry about setting autocomplete to a field multiple
> times, it is supposed to work like this when you need to change the
> source.

Tried it and as expected, `$.ajax()` initiated an XMLHttpRequest request upon page load, and not as desired when the user enters a character into the search input.

How am I able to make an XMLHttpRequest to source the data into the plugin?  I am assuming that I should be using a promise, however, if not, still would appreciate any assistance.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's how plugin supposed to work. Its meat and potatoes is `createItems` function, called on keyup event - and responsible for filling out that dropdown with items. And here's its key part ([1.3.0 version](https://github.com/Honatas/bootstrap-4-autocomplete/blob/v1.3.0/src/bootstrap-4-autocomplete.ts#L59)):

```
function createItems(field: JQuery < HTMLElement > , opts: AutocompleteOptions) {
  const lookup = field.val() as string;

  // ...
  
  let count = 0;
  const keys = Object.keys(opts.source);
  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    const key = keys[i];
    const object = opts.source[key];
    const item = {
      label: opts.label ? object[opts.label] : key,
      value: opts.value ? object[opts.value] : object,
    };
    if (item.label.toLowerCase().indexOf(lookup.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
      items.append(createItem(lookup, item, opts));
      if (opts.maximumItems > 0 && ++count >= opts.maximumItems) {
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  // skipped the rest
}
```

As you can see, each time `createItems` is called, it goes through `source` object, grepping all the items containing lookup string.

So all the data parts are expected to be there - and to be processable synchronously. That's the plugin's way, with all good and bad coming out of this approach.

The best thing the plugin's author could've suggested here (without going against what plugin is about) is using AJAX to prepopulate the data before calling autocomplete. And that's what he did in that comment actually.

---

Now, what can be done here? One might think it's enough just to transform `createItems` into an async function - for example, calling `source` if it's a function and expecting its result to be a Promise. It seems to be seductively simple excluding that lookup loop in process - and just take the the results of that AJAX call to repopulate `source`...

But that's not so simple, unfortunately: there are several caveats to be aware of. What should happen, for example, if user stops typing (triggering first AJAX call), then types some more, then stops once again (triggering another AJAX call) - but the first one actually arrives later? The corresponding bug was plaguing a lot of autocomplete implementations I've been working with, sadly - it's not that easy to reproduce if you're testing only with fast network connections (let alone only on localhost).

That's just one of the reasons the author decided against extending that plugin, it seems. After all, it was built to solve one specific task - and it does this well. So unless you want to fork it and essentially rewrite it into 'two strategies' one, I'd suggest considering looking somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you raina77ow,  Had been going down a rabbit hole and was suspecting there might not be another opening.  Glad I now know!

Comment: Hello again,  Been looking over the code you posted and thought "When did Javascript support interfaces????"  Searched and could find nothing.  Then  unfortunately discovered  I was fooled.  https://www.typescriptlang.org/  Thanks again for your answer.